# BackgroundWorker or Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am using a background service now to process a time consuming operation and same time showing progress in UI

But now looking for some performance improvements in terms of time [since at present background worker took more time to complete the processings]

The current solution of Do_Work in background worker is like

```
foreach(string _entry in ArrayList){

  //process the _entry(communicate to a service and store response in Db) and took almost 2-3 seconds for the completion
}
```

ArrayList contains almost 25000 records . So almost 25000*3 = 75000 seconds time is required to do the processing now

The new solution i am thinking of is like  starting  50 Threads of 500 items each at same time and waits for the completion of all Threads something like this

```
int failed = 0;
var tasks = new List<Task>();            
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {

        try
        {
            //Process 500 items from Array .(communicate to a service and store response in Db)
        }
        catch
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref failed);
            throw;
        }
    }));
}
Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);    //Runs 50 Threads         
try
{
    await t;
}
catch (AggregateException exc)
{
string _error="";
    foreach (Exception ed in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
    {
       _error+=ed.Message;
    }
     MessageBox.Show(_error);
}
if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    MessageBox.Show("All ping attempts succeeded.");
else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
    MessageBox.Show("{0} ping attempts failed", failed.ToString());
```

Will this helps to reduce the processing time? Or some better approaches?
I tried with a small sample size of 10 and debugged , but i cant see much difference (Something is wrong in my choice of WhenAll ?)

Comment: Well, you can use `PLINQ` and `Parallel.ForEach`...

Comment: Have you looked at Parallel.For/ForEach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: What does _Process 500 items from Array_ do?

Comment: its all depends on number of core machine have , so if you have two core machine and if you create 50 thread then it will be time slicing between then and that also cause performance issue, you need to code accoridng to number of phsical core

Comment: Is this IO bound or CPU bound?

Comment: The better question is, does your machine support running 50 threads concurrently?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - yes thats correct question here, need to figure out number of physical cores that can handle request accordingly

Comment: WhenAll will wait for all tasks to complete

Comment: @ChiragMM Have you seen possibility of using any  other combinations  here to make it quick?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle few records at a time.

Process n records with n different tasks. Let's say n = 5. So 5 different tasks t1,t2,t3,t4 and t5. Once anyone is completed processing data one row they should start processing t (1+n), t (2+n), t(3+n),t(4+n), t(5+n) row and so on until all records are processed.

Store all those processed values into a dictionary or list to identify which one belongs to which record.

It's like recursive function.

I have used this kind of approach in past and it really improves the performance a lot. You can fine-tune the value of n based on your PC configuration

Comment: So you are suggesting to use 5 Threads ? instead of BackgroundWorker

Comment: Not thread, use Task along with BackgroundWorker. Call a function from Backgroundworker and use 5 task insider that function. Number 5 is not fixed, keep it as a variable which you can adjust as per the performance.

Comment: @JibinMathew Please mark it as answer if you are able to improve performance using the approach suggested by me.

Comment: Np let me know if you need more help

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to try with [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)